# Practice versus Practice

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

We need to have a tag for practice which refers to the act of preparation for musical performance (which we already have) and a separate tag for practice which refers to performance practice, which is the study of the instruments, techniques, sounds, philosophies,  and other variables that contribute to a given historical style of music (which I cannot find). This is often used when referring to, say, the music of Bach, and in distinguishing the style of interpretation of employed by a modern post-romantic symphony orchestra from a historically informed performance (HIP) style, using the instruments, strings, bows, performance etiquette (i.e. most musicians often standing), etc. often employed by groups like the Academy of Ancient Music

My question is, what should that tag be? Is there already such a tag that I did not find when attempting to search for it?

Answer (score 5):

According to the [Tag Wiki](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/practice), [practice](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/practice) is the everyday tag: "Learning a skill by repeatedly rehearsing it." It makes sense because this is the tag that I'd expect to be in higher usage, as well as the definition assumed by beginners to the site.

Practice as a school of techniques might best be tagged by the particular practice itself (i.e. [romance](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/romance) [classical](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/classical) [baroque](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/baroque), even [bach](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bach)).

Consider, that on the Stack Exchange network, we discourage the use of [meta-tags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) - that is, a tag that only gives meaning in conjunction with another tag. Perhaps what you're suggesting wouldn't quite fit this definition, but I do think it's borderline - would anyone really search for questions on *all* practices?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming we need the latter (and my gut feeling is that it would be useful), I suggest renaming [practice](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/practice) to [practicing](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/practicing) (for clarity) and adding [performance-practice](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance-practice).  Anybody looking for either who starts to type the word "practice" will see both options before finishing the word.